# CSS position on different screens

Tags: html, css, position

When I'm trying to give my logo a position, it looks ok on my screen. But if I make the screen smaller or browse from a phone, the logo moves either to the center or glitches out of the header. The menu has the same issue. Why does this happen?

CSS:

```
#logo {
    margin-left: 20%;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.navigation {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.navigation li {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 10px;
}
```

Html:

```
<header>
    <div class="header">
    <div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
        <div id="headnav">
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Shop</li>
                <li>Rank</li>
                <li>Free</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondheader">
    </div>
    <div class="thirdheader">
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: http://justxp.plutohost.net/survive/index.html

Comment: Could you be a little more clear about how you are expecting it to behave?

Comment: And how can I fix this? basically i want the logo to be on left side, and menu to be on right sdie inside the 960px grid.

Answer (score 2):

Your margins are way to big. That's why they look like that on small screens.
The logo has this style :

```
margin-left: 350px;
padding: 20px;
float: left;
```

That gives it 350px margin, and after that you have a huge margin on the menu of 400px after you add those up it bigger then normal device resolution itself.

Comment: well it depends how you want to position things on different screens. you could use media queries to have different margins or give different floating on different kind of devices.

Comment: @user1604220 The search term you'll want to use when researching solutions is "responsive web design".

Comment: Well basically I want the logo and menu to be on the 960 grid area, yet the logo will still be on the left side, and menu will be on the right side, just inside the 960 grid.

Comment: do you want the site to scale white-space on mobile devices? if so, you need to code it specifically to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to center the stuff in your header. (And if you are, you're doin it wrong :P)

you should be using `margin:0 auto;` on some kinda container for that.

I think you want something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="margin-center">
    <div id="logo">
      LOGO
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
      stuff on the right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.header{width:100%;}
.margin-center{margin:0 auto;max-width:960px;}
#logo{float:left;}
#nav{float:right;}
```

---

EDIT: It may not have worked because of all the other styles you have in there.

If you could, please try this -

**ADD THIS TO YOUR CSS**

```
.margin_center {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 19px;
    min-width: 600px;
}
#headnav {
    float: right;
}
```

**CHANGE THIS IN YOUR CSS**

```
#logo {
    margin-left: 350px;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

to

```
#logo {
    float: left;
}
```

**AND CHANGE THIS**

```
.navigation {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

to

```
.navigation {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

**AND CHANGE THIS HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
    <div id="headnav">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Shop</li>
            <li>Rank</li>
            <li>Free</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="margin_center">
        <div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
        <div id="headnav">
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Shop</li>
                <li>Rank</li>
                <li>Free</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, the they want the logo on the left and the navigation/menu on the right, per the comment on the OP.

Comment: This just centered my logo, and the nav went under it but abit to right side

Comment: PS... look at the CSS on the part that works. The part that comes with bootstrap.css. it's using `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` which is essentially margin:0 auto;

Comment: look at the styles applied to `container` (in `header`) on your site. They're exactly what I said in the first place. Would you mind confirming the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, you want your logo image on the left, and your navigational text on the right. The easiest solution would be to float your image left, float your navigation right, and clear the floats.

Then your HTML would be something like this:

```
<header>
    <div class="header">
        <div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
            <div id="headnav">
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Shop</li>
                    <li>Rank</li>
                    <li>Free</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
...
```

And then in your CSS:

```
#logo {
    float: left;
}
.navigation {
    float: right;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ySyNy/) example. (The image has an explicit larger size to make it more obvious, FYI. You can resize the Results panel to see the differences.)

Comment: This has worked man, but I want them both on the 960 grid so it fits the whole template

 
justxp.plutohost.net/survive/index.html
Can you see the grid here? the 4 boxes per row? i want the logo and menu be between them

Comment: @user1604220 -- Then add a `max-width: 960px` and `margin: 0 auto;` on `.header`. That will center the header but leave the internal bits positioned as you need them.

Comment: Thanks man it worked, id made everything at the site 960px, so under it I placed another orange background but now the slider ignores the other backgrounds under the header, why?
http://gyazo.com/bbd3971d333445faf937ecc189005b08